# Why -1 causes key error in pandas dataframe post resetting its index and how to make it work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Lets say I have a pandas dataframe and the -1 indexing does not work post resetting its index. How do I make it work as it was earlier and why it doesn't work in this case?:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
list(data.reset_index()['Date'])[-1]
```

I dont think reset_index() as anything to do with it. Choosing a specific column from a dataframe returns a series. We may need to cast it to a list to access via negative index position.

This is a small example I tried on a sample dummy df:

```
'''
year    key val
2019    a   3
2019    a   4
2019    b   3
2019    c   5
2020    d   6
2020    e   1
2020    f   2
'''

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()

print(df)
```

Source df:

```
   year  key  val
0  2019  a      3
1  2019  a      4
2  2019  b      3
3  2019  c      5
4  2020  d      6
5  2020  e      1
6  2020  f      2
```

Both of these throw key error:

```
mask = df['year'][-1]
print(mask)
```

or

```
mask = df.reset_index()['year'][-1]
print(mask)
```

Output:

```
KeyError: -1
```

Both of these work:

```
mask = list(df.reset_index()['year'])[-1]
```

or

```
mask = list(df['year'])[-1]
```

Output:

```
2020
```

Comment: Yes this works. But why this casting was never required before resetting its index

Comment: Because the reset_index() is getting applied to a dataframe. and when you access a specific column of that dataframe, its a pandas.series. Worth researching more though, I dont claim that my explanation is beyond correction :).

Comment: Infact, I just tried it on a random sample dummy df, it wont work without reset_index as well, it seems. That is data['Date'][-1] should also throw the same error.

Comment: That throws err as the Date is index in that original df

Comment: I am adding one small example to my answer on what I tried, to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the `df.loc()` or `df.iloc()` property.
In your case that might be
(see the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas.DataFrame.iloc)).

```py
data.rerset_index()['Date'].iloc(-1)
```

Instead of resetting the index, you also could simply write `data.index[-1]`.